# Google Search Appliance Reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-search, google-search-appliance

We use GSA 7.2 and have more than 500k docs in index from large number of subdomains. I am looking for Page where search was performed. GSA is integrated with Google Analytics already. When I look in Search Terms, I see the terms searched on but I can not tell which site from the collection user was on as GA includes only URI ie /search?q=...... I tried looking in Referral too but no success. Any answers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is old, but going to answer anyway.

The Google Search Appliance does not track the Referrer (the web page that sent the GET request).

This leaves you with two options to collect that data:
1) Insert a web proxy between your site(s) and the GSA(s).  This can have a performance impact of 250-500 ms, so don't use this option if blazing speed is a priority.  You would have this proxy log the Referrer and the GET URL, so that you can match that to the reports from the GSA.

2) Rearrange your Collections to reflect the sites that could be sending requests.  You can have a max of 200 Collections without impacting performance, so this should work for you unless you have an already complicated arrangement of Collections.

```
   a) An arrangement by Site only could look like this:
        - fromIntranetSite
        - fromMarketingSite
        - fromTokyoSite
        - fromHQIntranet
        ...
    b) An arrangement by contents and by Site could look like this:
        - FAQsfromIntranetSite
        - ProductsFromMarketingSite
        - ResourcesFromHQIntranet
        ...
```